# foreignkey assignment error python django model

Tags: python, django

**models.py**
i have create foreignkey in table paymentsDetails i have stripe payment method which is working when user login session is created and by using session value i get the primarykey of that user by using 'ORM' method and then assign this primary key of specific user into the paymentdetails models field named as user_account_id
but i am getting error that i cannot assign 1 to PaymentsDetail.User_account_id must be a instance of UserAccountModel

```
class UserAccountModel(models.Model):

ContactEmail = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
LastName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
Counrty = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Phone = models.IntegerField()
ChooseUserName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
EnterCaptcha = models.CharField(max_length=4)
payments = models.BooleanField(max_length=6, default=False)
showsponsor = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=False)
RegisteredDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
ActivationOn = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False,blank=True)
expiry_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False,blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.FirstName + ":" + self.ChooseUserName



class PaymentsDetail(models.Model):

refrer_name = models.CharField(max_length=32,default="", editable=False)
sponser_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
status = models.CharField(default='comped', max_length=32)
s_id = models.CharField(max_length=32)
registered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
activated_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
Due_Date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
payment = models.CharField(default='$',max_length=32)
User_Account_id = models.ForeignKey(UserAccountModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True, editable=True)

addprogrameReference = models.ForeignKey(AddProgramModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True, editable=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['User_Account_id', 'addprogrameReference']
```

def **str**(self):
    return self.refrer_name + ":" + self.user_account

> i am getting the error
>
> cannot assign 1 to PaymentsDetail.User_account_id  must be a instance
>   of UserAccountModel

**views.py**

```
                print("user payment"+str(charge.amount))
                pays = str(charge.amount)
                user_id = random.randint(0, 999)  # returns a random integer
                user = User.objects.get(username=str(rerredby))
                userKey = user.pk
                print("this one is for user upper")
                # saving record
                payment_insertion = PaymentsDetail.objects.create(
                    User_Account_id=userKey,
                    refrer_name=rerredby,
                    sponser_name=rerredby,
                    s_id=str(user_id),
                    registered=datetime.now(),
                    activated_date=datetime.now(),
                    Due_Date=datetime.now(),
                    payment=str(pays + "$"),
                )
                payment_insertion.save()
```

Comment: Have you read documentation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey ForeignKey field appends `_id` itself generating migration. It's the first.

Comment: It would be better to post the full stacktrace. The main issue is when you call `PaymentDetail.objects.create`, as a `User_Account_id` you should pass not `userKey` but user. Hope it can answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change this string:

```
payment_insertion = PaymentsDetail.objects.create(
                User_Account_id=user,
                ...)
```

You are trying to assign int object where Django expects an instance.

Comment: but i want to add pk manually i think User_Account_id=user, is geting the id auto,automatically from the user model.

Comment: yes, it's getting it automatically, but I do not see in your code that you actually adding PK manually - you just retrieving it from user instance and setting on `User_Account_id`. If you want to manually define PK then you can simply first fetch the corresponding `User` record by `User.objects.get(id=your_manual_id)` and then in same way pass it to `PaymentsDetail` create method.

Comment: payment_insertion = PaymentsDetail.objects.create(
                User_Account_id=user.pk,
                ...)

Answer (score 0):

Your view implementation is not right. The model class expects the field `User_Account_id` to be an instance of of `UserAccountModel` (since, your model definition `User_Account_id = models.ForeignKey(UserAccountModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True, editable=True)` told it to expect it regardless of the your field name ending with an id). therefore, retrieve the `UserAccountModel` instance from db first.

However, if you still want to pass the id to instead of an object change the following in your view.

```py
User_Account_id_id=userKey
```

ForeingKey fields can be populated by id instead of the concerned model object. But you have to append `_id` at the end of the field name e.g.

```py
#models.py

class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class Book(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   author = models.ForeignKeyField(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


# views.py

def create_book(request):
   name = request.POST.get('name', '')
   author_id = request.POST.get('author_id', '')

   Book.objects.create(name=name, author_id=author_id)

   return HttpResponse(status=201)
```

Notice that there is no `author_id` field defined in the `Book` model. This field is implicitly defined by django ORM once you defined `author` field as a ForeignKey reference to `Author` model.